# MAC verification failed during PKCS12 import (wrong password?) / Azure Devops

Tags: ios, azure-devops, yaml, certificate

I'm using the InstallAppleCertificate@2 task from Azure DevOps but each time I try running it this error pops up

```
security: SecKeychainItemImport: MAC verification failed during PKCS12 import (wrong password?)
```

this is the task I'm using

```
- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
inputs:
  certSecureFile: "${{ parameters.certificateSecureFileName }}"
  certPwd: "${{ parameters.certificatePassword }}"
displayName: "Install AdHoc Certificate"
```

I'm pretty sure the password is correct since I tried the same command locally and it worked. Password doesn't contain any special characters and is being stored in a variables group.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 18, accepted):

OpenSSL 3.x changed its default algorithm in `pkcs12`. Which is not compatible with embedded Security frameworks in macOS/iOS. You could alternatively use OpenSSL 1.x.

See:

- [Change default algorithms in PKCS12_create() and PKCS12_set_mac()](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/762970bd686c4aa8ea7169e7f76d5a4ce665da93)
- [MacOS security framework fails to import RFC 7292 compliant PKCS #12 v1.1 file into keychain using modern cyphers](https://openradar.appspot.com/FB8988319)

To macOS users: If you're using `openssl@3` command line tool installed via Homebrew, downgrade to `openssl@1.1` and modify your `PATH` in `~/.zshrc`. For example:

```sh
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/bin:$PATH"
```

```sh
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"
```

If you're using `openssl@3` libraries (`libcrypto` and `libssl`) with `SecKeychainItemImport` or `SecPKCS12Import`, have a look at the commit page above and do some modifications to your codes.

Comment: You made my day, thanks for the info, I was using OpenSSL 3.x instead, could not find the reason anywhere as of why I got this error. Thanks!

Comment: Same for me. I was trying to use Ionic's appflow to build an iOS app and this error was showing up in their build system's logs. I had no clue where to even start until I saw your answer. Thanks!

Comment: I found @jarrod Modrich's command line which included the export param most useful

Answer (score 32):

The first link in @i_82 's answer says this:

> The pkcs12 application now supports -legacy option that restores the previous default algorithms to support interoperability with legacy systems.

If you have control over the arguments when exporting, using the `-legacy` option should solve the problem without needing to install an old version of openssl:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -legacy -out Certificate.p12 -in certificate.pem -inkey key.pem
```

Comment: 10.12 High Sierra, Homebrew, openssl@3 ... added `-legacy` solved the error

Comment: 13.5 Ventura, Homebrew `openssl@3`: adding `-legacy` worked - thank you 

Comment: ^^ This is the answer to hours of trial, error, and searching ^^.
Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

This bit me on MacOS Sonoma today as well (for a user certificate issued to me today by Sectigo), so it looks like the missing functionality for PKCS12 import is *still* not implemented by Apple.

The [radar](https://openradar.appspot.com/FB8988319) [linked by i_82](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70656724/2333678) in the accepted answer is IMO a bit hard to understand, and I don't think the accepted answer of downgrading to OpenSSL version 1 should be neccesary. For me, converting the PKCS12 file to the "legacy" format, as [stated in Jarrod Moldrich's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74792849/2333678), worked fine.

To explain what this does, you can take a look at the "legacy" and "non-legacy" version of a keypair in PKCS12 format like so:

```bash
$ openssl pkcs12 -info -noout -in modern.p12
Enter Import Password:
MAC: sha256, Iteration 10000
MAC length: 32, salt length: 20
PKCS7 Data
Shrouded Keybag: PBES2, PBKDF2, AES-256-CBC, Iteration 10000, PRF hmacWithSHA256
PKCS7 Encrypted data: PBES2, PBKDF2, AES-256-CBC, Iteration 10000, PRF hmacWithSHA256
Certificate bag
Certificate bag
Certificate bag
```

and for the legacy file:

```bash
$ openssl pkcs12 -info -noout -legacy -in legacy.p12
Enter Import Password:
MAC: sha1, Iteration 2048
MAC length: 20, salt length: 8
PKCS7 Encrypted data: pbeWithSHA1And40BitRC2-CBC, Iteration 2048
Certificate bag
Certificate bag
Certificate bag
PKCS7 Data
Shrouded Keybag: pbeWithSHA1And3-KeyTripleDES-CBC, Iteration 2048
```

As you can see, the encryption format for the private key changes between the two forms, with the legacy format using the quite old ["TripleDES" (3DES) encryption](https://csrc.nist.gov/glossary/term/triple_data_encryption_standard), and the modern version using AES-256-CBC, which is [much more secure](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/51629/is-triple-des-still-considered-safe-to-use). 3DES (or 3TDEA, as it's called by NIST) is also no longer allowable for FIPS purposes as per the latest revision [of the relevant NIST standard](https://doi.org/10.6028/NIST.SP.800-57pt1r5), where it states on page 54:

> Although 3TDEA is listed as providing 112 bits of security strength, its use has been deprecated (see [SP 800-131A](https://doi.org/10.6028/NIST.SP.800-131Ar2))
> through 2023, after which it will be **disallowed for applying cryptographic protection**. The use of a deprecated
> algorithm means that the algorithm or key length may be used if the risk of doing so is acceptable.

Using OpenSSL 3, you can export the encrypted keypair using:

```bash
$ openssl pkcs12 -in modern.p12 -out keypair.pem
```

which will prompt you for an export password for the keypair, and write both the private key (encrypted) and the fullchain of the certificate into `keypair.pem`.

Next, convert the keypair into the legacy format using:

```bash
$ openssl pkcs12 -export -legacy -in keypair.pem -out legacy.p12 -name "name you want in the p12 file"
```

This will prompt you for a password three time, the first time it's asking you for the keypair password, and then for the export password. You can set the name of the PKCS12 entry using the `-name` switch, if you leave it out it's just going to name the entry `1`. But at the end of the day, it doesn't really matter what the entry is called for almost all applications.

The legacy file should be able to be imported into Keychain Access now. In the terminal, you can also do this using `security`.

First, find the location of your `login` keychain:

```bash
$ sudo security list-keychains
    "/Users/foobar/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db"
    "/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
```

Then, import the entry using:

```bash
sudo security import /path/to/legacy.p12 -k /Users/foobar/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db -f pkcs12
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/7293):

What works for me is this:

```
openssl  pkcs12 -passout pass:test123 -export -in etestcerts.pem -keypbe PBE-SHA1-3DES -certpbe PBE-SHA1-3DES -macalg sha1 -out etest-ossl3-3des-sha1.p12`
```

***The key here is specifying the algorithms.***

Comment: Thank you so much for this, this did the trick.  Trying to use the -legacy command as stated above resulted in errors I couldn't resolve.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it failed because the password had special characters in it.  I don't know exactly which characters are supported but there are some that cause problems.  I changed the password to not use any special character and it worked.  It looks like the azure task could be improve to support this.  I was able to use my password with special characters in the command line (openssl pkcs12 ...) if I surround it with double quotes.  I suppose there would be some encoding required to support this when there is a double quote in the password.

Bottom line, at the moment, some special characters do not work in the password for the azure task InstallAppleCertificate.

Also the error I was getting is slightly different:

```
Mac verify error: invalid password?
unable to load certificate
```